# How do you use exception handling in visual basic?

Tags: excel, vba

How do you handle exceptions in visual basic?

Answer (score 4):

VBA doesn't call it exception handling, rather it calls it error handling and it has a different syntax than what can be found in VB.Net or Java etc.

You need to research the `On Error` statement, specifically the `On Error Goto <LABEL>` where you can say that if any error occurs, then go to the specified label where you put your error handling code.

You can also tell the code to ignore errors by doing `On Error Resume Next`, but this should normally only be used very sparingly for as few lines as possible and then needs to be followed by `On Error Goto 0` to reset the error handling.

See these articles for more information:
[Error Trapping with Visual Basic for Applications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146864)
[Error Handling In VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ErrorHandling.htm)

Comment: I think the way VBA error handling works meets any reasonable definition of "exception handling". True, VBA EH is not object-oriented, and its syntax is clunky, but the first line of your post is wrong and should be edited.